# How can I pre-load a route in flutter, or keep a widget loaded even when it is off screen?

Tags: flutter, quill

I am using GoRouter to navigate between pages of my app. One of the routes that I navigate is using the QuillHtmlEditor, which takes ~1 second to load when I navigate to it, and it loads fresh each time the user navigates to the page. I would like to keep the page with the QuillHtmlEditor loaded at all times regardless of whether it is on the screen. Is there a way to do this easily? I am having a very hard time finding any information about how to preload a route in flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to keep the page with the QuillHtmlEditor loaded at all times regardless of whether it is on the screen

You can use the [`Offstage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) widget:

> A widget that lays the child out as if it was in the tree, but without painting anything, without making the child available for hit testing, and without taking any room in the parent.

```
Offstage(
      offstage: _offstage,
      child: Container(
        child: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
    ),
```

Or, as an alternative, you can use [`IndexedStack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html):

> A Stack that shows a single child from a list of children.
> The displayed child is the one with the given index. The stack is always as big as the largest child.

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: <Widget>[
          Widget1(),
          Widget2(),
          // ... other pages
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, the concept of **pre-loading** a route isn’t really a thing.

A common solution is keeping the state of the widget's controller that you want to **"pre-load"** stored in a higher scope. In your case it would be storing the [QuillEditor's](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_quill_custom/latest/flutter_quill/QuillEditor-class.html) respective [QuillController](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_quill_custom/latest/flutter_quill/QuillController-class.html), and storing it globally is probably the best way.
Using this method, even if the widget is removed from the tree and added back, it will still maintain its state.

Another solution, albeit a sketchy one depending on the context, is using a [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) for certain sections of your app. This allows you to keep all its children pages loaded in the widget tree, maintaining their state as long as they are inside the **PageView**.
It is, of course, not a suitable approach for sections with a large number of pages or performance heavy ones.

The [Offstage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) and [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) function in a similar way to the **PageView**, you will merely be **"hidding"** the widget while it is not used, so that it is not reloaded when you need it.

Using any of these last three widgets will allow the Quill editor to still use CPU and drain battery as if it was in active use inside the widget tree, which is why I recommend following the global / higher scope controller storage approach.