# Avoid disposing stateful widget when it's not visible

Tags: flutter

I have a Stateful widget `WidgetOne` that I'm wrapping into a `Visibility` widget to control its visibility.
The goal is to have multiple created at the same time but only one visible (for a desktop-like tabs behavior).

Listview to show "tab bar":

```
ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
               for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) 
                  InkWell(
                     onTap: () => setSate(() =>_index = i), 
                     child: Text('Element $i'),
                  )
            ]
),
```

The Column that creates all `WidgetOne` widgets and make only 1 visible at a time (depending on _index value):

```
Column(
  children: [
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
       Visibility(
          visibile: i == _index,
          child: WidgetOne() //My stateful widget which I want it to avoid dispose
       )
]
)
```

With this implementation, each time `_index` value is updated and the state is rebuilt, the `dispose()` methods of all non visible WidgetOne widgets are called and they are removed from the widget tree.

Is there any way to make sure that they are not disposed but only hidden instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`Offstage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) widget:

> A widget that lays the child out as if it was in the tree, but without painting anything, without making the child available for hit testing, and without taking any room in the parent.

```dart
Offstage(
   offstage: _offstage,
```

And/or see my other [How can I pre-load a route in flutter, or keep a widget loaded even when it is off screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77744050/12349734) for using `IndexedStack`

Comment: IndexStack worked for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `maintainState` property to `true`.

```dart
Visibility(
  maintainState: true,
  // ...
)
```

In the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility/maintainState.html), the `maintainState` property is described as:

> Whether to maintain the State objects of the child subtree when it is not visible.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question but setting maintainState to true lets the widget occupy a visual space even if it's not visible (blank space).
As if the widget is there but showing blank